# How to us .active in foreach loop

Tags: php, css, foreach

I'm trying to give the active menu item a different color but the color stays on the first menu item (Home). I already put a active class in my css.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$menu = array(
    array('text' => 'Home', 'link' => 'index.php', 'target' => NULL),
    array('text' => 'Contact', 'link' => 'contact.php', 'target' => NULL),
    array('text' => 'Video', 'link' => 'video.php', 'target' => NULL), 
    array('text' => 'Thema', 'link' => 'thema.php', 'target' => NULL),
    array('text' => 'Numbers', 'link' => 'numbers.php', 'target' => NULL),
    array('text' => 'Login', 'link' => 'login.php', 'target' => NULL),
    array('text' => 'Logout', 'link' => 'indexlogout.php', 'target' => NULL),
    array('text' => 'Links', 'link' => 'links.php', 'target' => NULL),
    array('text' => 'Image Maps', 'link' => 'imagemap.php', 'target' => NULL)
);

function makeMenu($menu){
    $current_page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $current_page = str_replace('.php', '', $current_page);

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($menu as $key => $value){
        if($current_page == $key){
            echo '<li><a class="active" href="'.$value['link'].'" target="'.$value['target'].'">'.$value['text'].'</a></li>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$value['link'].'" target="'.$value['target'].'">'.$value['text'].'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

makeMenu($menu);
```

?>

Comment: `$key` or `$value['text']`??, i think `if($current_page == $key){` should be `if($current_page == $value['text']){`

Comment: so what is in your REQUEST_URI? You're comparing that against `$key`, which is a purely numeric value. are your pages REALLY named `0.php`, `1.php`, etc...?

Comment: Your $current_page is trying to equal 'text' ($key) try doing this $current_page == $value

Comment: Without limiting SEO, you should add a `active_field` in your array so you can name your files other things not just 'Home' (limiting filenames to your navigation names)

Answer (score 0):

The `$key` in the foreach will be a numeric one. For first item will be 0 for example, and I think this is not what you need.

You need to change it and check with the `link` value from `$value`

```
function makeMenu($menu){
    $current_page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($menu as $value){
        if($current_page == $value['link']){
            echo '<li><a class="active" href="'.$value['link'].'" target="'.$value['target'].'">'.$value['text'].'</a></li>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$value['link'].'" target="'.$value['target'].'">'.$value['text'].'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```